# Cannot locate the raspeberry pi pico on my computer (`UF2_Board ` instead of `/dev/cu.usbserial-0001`)

Tags: usb, arduino, pi-pico

I want to connect to upload code on my raspberry-pi-pico but my computer does not recognize it. When using the arduino cli it seems to be recognized under the `UF2_Board`  instead of the classical `/dev/cu.usbserial-xxxx` label.

If I first plug an esp32, I can locate it as follows (using `ls` and `arduino cli`:

```
$ ls /dev/tty.*
...
/dev/tty.usbserial-0001
...
$ arduino-cli board list
Port                              Protocol Type              Board Name FQBN Core
...
/dev/cu.usbserial-0001            serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown
...
```

It is recognized both with ls and arduino-cli. If I now connect raspberry pi pico with the same usb port on my machine (Macbook pro retina 15 inches, macOS 11.6.1), and use the same commands, I get the following output:

```
$ ls /dev/tty.*
...
/dev/tty.usbserial-0001
...
$ arduino-cli board list
Port                              Protocol Type              Board Name FQBN Core
...
UF2_Board                         uf2conv  UF2 Devices Unknown
```

Additionally, I want to mention that I could successfully upload code on the ESP32. So I assume that the usb cable can both transfer power and data, that the usb cable works and that the usb socket on the computer work as well